# Pig latin translator not handling vowel 'a'

Tags: python

Pig latin translator not working properly .Not showing output for vowel 'a'.

example: input: va

the output is an error showing reference error.
working properly for all other vowels except 'a'.

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'list3' referenced before assignment.

```
import string

def translate(str1):

    str2="eaiouy"
    list2=[]
    punstr=""
    for c in str1:
        if c in string.punctuation:
            punstr=punstr+c
    for c in string.punctuation:
        str1= str1.replace(c,"")
    if str1.isdigit():
        return str1+punstr
    else:
        if (len(str1)==1):
            if str1[0] in str2:
                return str1+"yay"+punstr
            else:
                return str1+"ay"+punstr
        elif str1[0] in str2:
            return str1+"yay"+punstr
        else:
            for i in str2:
                list1=str1.split(i)
                if (len(list1[0])<len(list2)):
                    list3=list1[0]
                list2=list1[0]
            prestr=str(list3)
            stem=str1.split(list3)
            reqstem=stem[1]
            return reqstem+prestr+"ay"+punstr
while True:
    str1=raw_input("\nenter the sentance")
    sentlist=str1.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(sentlist)):
        mystr=sentlist[i]
        if i==0:
            reqstring=translate(mystr)
            print reqstring.capitalize(),
        else:
            reqstring=translate(mystr)
            print reqstring,
```

Comment: The error message tells you pretty much everything you need to know. If you look at the code it should be obvious that `list3` is not always defined, yet you treat it as if it were.

Comment: Please read the error !!

Comment: for some inputs it not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list3` is only assigned to when `len(list1[0]<len(list2)`, which means sometimes it *isn't* set, and that's when `prestr=str(list3)` will give you trouble.

Comment: when i giving input  "ve" it shows correct output.But when i give input as "va" shows error..means it not handing  vowel "a".can you help me

Answer (score 0):

**working now!!!**

```
import string

def translate(str1):

    vowel=" eaiouy"
    list2=[]
    punstr=""
    for c in str1:
        if c in string.punctuation:
            punstr=punstr+c
    for c in string.punctuation:
        str1= str1.replace(c,"")
    if str1.isdigit():
        return str1+punstr
    else:
        if (len(str1)==1):
            if str1[0] in vowel:
                return str1+"yay"+punstr
            else:
                return str1+"ay"+punstr
        elif str1[0] in vowel:
            return str1+"yay"+punstr
        else:
            for i in str1:
                if i in vowel:
                    list1=str1.split(i)
                    print list1
                    break

            prestr=str(list1[0])
            stem=str1.split(prestr)
            reqstem=stem[1]
            return reqstem+prestr+"ay"+punstr
while True:
    str1=raw_input("\nenter the sentance")
    sentlist=str1.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(sentlist)):
        mystr=sentlist[i]
        if i==0:
            reqstring=translate(mystr)
            print reqstring.capitalize(),
        else:
            reqstring=translate(mystr)
            print reqstring,
```